# Disprove the following statement If a function $y=f(x)$ is differentiable at the point $x=a$ and the point $(a,f(a))$ is a point of inflection ...

Tags: analysis, functions

I am required to disprove this statement, how would  I go about doing this?

If a function $y=f(x)$ is differentiable at the point $x=a$ and the point $(a,f(a))$ is a point of inflection on the function, then the second derivative is zero at that point

Comment: What is your definition of point of inflection? Because I think this follows by my definition.

Comment: The second derivative need not exist, example $f(x)=-x^2$ if $x\lt 0$, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Try with $f(x)=x|x|$